# How can I remove the external bounding box on image using cv2 python

Tags: python, opencv, bounding-box

I'm trying to create image-to-text converter using Opencv and python. I have created bounding boxes using cv2.findContours() function but my problem is, it is drawing bounding box at borders of the image too. I want the bounding boxes to draw on only letters and I don't want to draw box around the image as border. I'm using the cv2.findContours() as below:

```
roi = []
for cnt in contours:
    x, y, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(cnt)
    roi = img[y:y+h, x:x+w]
    cv2.rectangle(img, (x, y), (x+w, y+h), (200, 0, 0), 5)

cv2.imshow('img', img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Then it is giving me output like this [output image with cv2.RETR_CCOMP method](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uKhsH.png)

I tried using the cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL instead of cv2.RETR_CCOMP but the output I'm getting is as below.

[output image with cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL method](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5lVW3.png)

Please help me, how can I remove the outer bounding box and create box only for the letters.

Comment: Check for the box with the largest height and with and remove it from the list

Comment: Did it not give the 2-level hierarchy as mentioned here https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d3/dc0/group__imgproc__shape.html#ga819779b9857cc2f8601e6526a3a5bc71

Comment: @ai2ys Yes, it is creating 2-level hierarchy only but when I try to remove the external hierarchy contours, it is removing all the external contours around the letters too which is not what is needed. Anyways with your suggestion, I tried to draw contours which are less than the bigger contour on image and it worked. Thanks!

Comment: invert the picture. contours go around black-to-white edges

Comment: yes, @ChristophRackwitz I tried that also. It is the best way. Thanks..    Can you post this as answer so that I will accept it and someone gets benefit of it